# What does it mean for a set to be isometric with another set?

Tags: isometry

If a set $A$ is isometric with a set $B$, does that mean there exists an isometry from $A$ to $B$? Or is it the other way around, that there exists an isometry from $B$ to $A$?

Edit: I forgot that there were multiple definitions of an isometry, but my book's definition does not require it to be surjective. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **yes** to both questions. Any isometry is a bijection onto its range, and the inverse is also a bijection. This means that there exists an isometry such that $f(A)=B$ if and only if there exists an isometry $g$ such that $g(B)=A$.

Comment: I have updated my question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Jake It makes no difference. If $f : V_1 \to V_2$ is an isometry, then $f: V_1 \to Im(f) \subset V_2$ is a bijective isometry. If $f$ takes $A$ into $B$ then $B=f(A) \subset Im(f)$.

Comment: @Jake To spell out the argument, $f^{-1} : Im(f) \to V_1$ is an isometry which takes $B$ to $A$.

Comment: @Jake Or if your definition of isemetry is given at the level of sets $A,B$, not as an isometry of larger spaces which takes $A$ into $B$, then isometric sets MUST mean onto isometry between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Mine is specifically with sets that are metric spaces, but I didn't know it made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It means that there is a surjective isometry from $A$ to $B$ and it also means that there as a surjective isometry from $B$ to $A$. These assertions are equivalent.

Comment: I have updated my question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Jake My answer is still good.